# How does a Python recursive function works for tri_recursion function?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm new to Python, I found [the below recursive program](https://www.w3schools.com/python/showpython.asp?filename=demo_recursion) being tough to follow. While debugging the program I could find that it goes through recursion and the value of `k` decrements -1 every time we recurse. At one point `k` is -1 and the compiler moves to the `else` part and returns 0.

Finally, the `k` value turns out to be 1, how does this happen?

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k>0):
    result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

And the output:

```
Recursion Example Results  
1  
3  
6  
10  
15  
21
```

Comment: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20tri_recursion%28k%29%3A%0A%20%20if%28k%3E0%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20k%2Btri_recursion%28k-1%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28result%29%0A%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%200%0A%20%20return%20result%0A%0Aprint%28%22%5Cn%5CnRecursion%20Example%20Results%22%29%0Atri_recursion%286%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false  Use this visualization tool. It will help you how recursion is working using stack concept.

Comment: Look at this link too for better understanding http://cryptroix.com/2016/10/10/understanding-multiple-recursion/

Comment: I think [this](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Recursion-concept?pid=59503#pid59503) is a good visualization of what happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try tracing the function with a pencil and paper. In this case, the print statement insde the function may be a bit misleading.

Consider this part of the program,

```
if(k>0):
    result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)
...
```

From here,

```
tri_recursion(6) = 6 + tri_recursion(5)
```

So to get the result for `tri_recursion(6)` we must get the result of `tri_recursion(5)` Following this logic, the problem reduces to:

```
tri_recursion(6) 
 = 6 + tri_recursion(5) 
 = 6 + 5 + tri_recursion(4)
 = 6 + 5 + 4 + tri_recursion(3)
 = 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + tri_recursion(2)
 = 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + tri_recursion(1)
 = 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + tri_recursion(0)
```

Now notice that 0 is not greater than 0 so the program moves to the body of the else clause:

```
else:
    result = 0
...
```

Which means `tri_recursion(0) = 0`. Therefore:

```
tri_recursion(6) 
= 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + tri_recursion(0)
= 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0
= 21
```

### Points to note

1. In running this program.`k` is never equal to `-1`, infact it is impossible.
2. It is misleading to think of control flow in terms of "the compiler moving across a program". The compiler does't do anything during execution ([JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) is a different matter). It is better to think in terms of control flow / order of execution in procedual languages, equationally in functional programming and relations in logic programming.

Answer (score 2):

if you debug the code like this

```
def tri_recursion(k):
    if(k > 0):
        print('\t'*k,'start loop k',k)
        holder = tri_recursion(k - 1)
        result = k + holder
        print('\t'*k,'i am k(', k,')+previous result(', holder,')=',result)
    else:
        result = 0
        print('i reached when k =', k)
    print('\t'*k,'end loop', k)
    return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

you will see the output like

```
Recursion Example Results
                         start loop k 6
                     start loop k 5
                 start loop k 4
             start loop k 3
         start loop k 2
     start loop k 1
i reached when k = 0
 end loop 0
     i am k( 1 )+previous result( 0 )= 1
     end loop 1
         i am k( 2 )+previous result( 1 )= 3
         end loop 2
             i am k( 3 )+previous result( 3 )= 6
             end loop 3
                 i am k( 4 )+previous result( 6 )= 10
                 end loop 4
                     i am k( 5 )+previous result( 10 )= 15
                     end loop 5
                         i am k( 6 )+previous result( 15 )= 21
                         end loop 6
21
```