# Can someone explain this code that uses recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k>0):
    result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result
```

So I'm trying to learn recursion and I don't necessarily understand how it works here. If lets say K=6, why would the output be 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21?

Comment: If you believe in visualization of what the function does, here is something that you should try out. [Visualize code](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20tri_recursion%28k%29%3A%0A%20%20if%28k%3E0%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20k%2Btri_recursion%28k-1%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28result%29%0A%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%200%0A%20%20return%20result%0Atri_recursion%286%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

Comment: I hope you can get math, The recursion is `f(n) = n + f(n - 1)` for n > 0, given that `f(m) = 0` for all `m <= 0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do a python recursive function works for tri\_recursion function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578602/how-do-a-python-recursive-function-works-for-tri-recursion-function)

Comment: The most confusion might come from the reverse printing order since it is printing after returning from the recursion on the way down the stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
f(0) = 0  
f(1) = 1 + f(0)  
f(2) = 2 + f(1)  
....
```

when you try to evaluate any f(n) where n>0, you have to evaluate f(n-1) first. which means f(n1) will be evaluate before f(n2) if n1 < n2, which also means it print the result first.

Answer (score 0):

The `tri_recursion` function just sums up the numbers from 1 to `k`. You can see that by induction:

1. For `k = 0` the else block is executed and the claim is obvious, and
2. for `k > 0` the if block is executed which adds `k` to `tri_recursion(k - 1)`, and this is the sum of `1 + ... + (k - 1)` by induction hypothesis.

So, `tri_recursion(k) = 1 + 2 + ... + k`.

Answer (score 0):

One mental tool I like to use is to ask myself the following questions:

1. What is the trivial case (in this case the base case)
2. What is the simplest non-trivial case
3. What is the second simplest non-trivial case

For the following discussion, I'm going to restrict `k` to integer values.

### The simplest case (k <= 0)

If `k` <= 0, the result is just 0.

### Simplest non-trivial case (k = 1)

If `k` = 1, the result is `1 + tri_recursion(1 - 1)` = `1 + tri_recursion(0) = 1`

### Second simplest non-trivial case (k = 2)

If `k` = 2, the result is `2 + tri_recursion(1)` = `2 + 1 + tri_recursion(0) = 3`.

### Understanding this recursive algorithm

So we see that the solution for general value of `k` >= 1 is

0 + 1 + 2 + ... + k

because each time we call `tri_recursion(k)`, we add the `k` to the sum of `1 + 2 + ... + k - 1`. When `k` is finally 0, we return 0.

Try drawing out the chain of calls for a simple case of `k` = 2

```
k = 2
\
 2 + tri_recursion(1)
           \
            1 + tri_recursion(0)
                      \
                       0
```

which becomes

```
k = 2
\
  2 + tri_recursion(1)
            \
             1 + 0  # Prints 1 at this point
```

and then

```
k = 2
\
  2 + 1  # Prints 3 at this point
```

which finally gives 3.

Because you are printing each time `tri_recursion` returns for cases where `k` > 0, you see the outputs 1, 3 (= 2 + 1), 6 (= 3 + 2 + 1) ... in that order because of how the call stack unwinds.