# Recursion function inn python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to understand the recursion function. I would like to know how that answer is coming with steps

```
def tri_recursion(k):
  if(k>0):
    result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)
    print(result)
  else:
    result = 0
  return result

print("\n\nRecursion Example Results")
tri_recursion(6)
```

results are this just want to know how its coming

1
3
6
10
15
21

Comment: A good way to understand such a function step by step is to use a debugger and go through it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do a python recursive function works for tri\_recursion function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578602/how-do-a-python-recursive-function-works-for-tri-recursion-function)

Comment: `fibonacci`  series by recursion indeed...

Comment: @Riad, this is **not** the `fibonacci` series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function computes the sum of all numbers between 0 and n, and prints intermediate results. The first 1 is 0+1, the 3 = 0+1+2, 6 = 0+1+2+3, 10 = 0+1+2+3+4, ...

To understand a recursive function, you need 2 points : how is the recursive call done, and when does the recursion stop.

The recursive call is given by `result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)`and the recursion stops when `k <= 0`and returns 0. So if we assume only positive numbers, we could describe tri_recursion so:

```
tri_recursion(k) = k + tri_recursion(k-1) if k > 0
tri_recursion(0) = 0
```

So `tri_recursion(k) = k + tri_recursion(k-1) = k + (k-1) + tri_recursion(k-2) = k + (k-1) + (k-2) + tri_recursion(k-3) ... = k + (k-1) + (k-2) + ... + 0`

So `tri_recursion(k)` is the sum of all numbers between 0 and k.

Note that the sum on all numbers between 0 and k equals `k*(k+1) / 2` so `tri_recursion(6) = 6 * 7 / 2 = 21`